# Open Power Shell as Admin on remote VM

Tags: python, windows, powershell, admin, pyvmomi

I have a python that uses pyvmomi library of VMWare to perform operations on remote VM.
I open the remote VM cmd prompt  using Pyvmomi library like this

```
vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.ProgramSpec(
        programPath="C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe")
```

Is there any way to open Power Shell as Admin or any code that can be added in the script to run it as Admin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the powershell script as administrator:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25247612/1763602

You can create another script that will launch your script with elevated privileges.

Comment: @Macro Sulla - as said on the link u specify i do RUNAS  /user:user@domain.microsoft.com "powershell pshell.ps1" it ask for admin passwd

Comment: @user1312155: there are other solution listed in the answer. One is `psexec`: http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html If you don't have it, you have to install Sysinternal tools.

Comment: @Macro Sulla i can't use any other tool except VMWare Tools

Comment: You can run `runas` with `/savecred` on VM, password will be stored. I don't linke this solution for security reasons, but it will work. That said, `pstools` are now an official Microsoft tool and needs no install.